# JavaScript only loads once per tab? (Multiple "pages" with tables in single page)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket

Alright, so I'm creating a script to avoid activating a link in a parent div. I've added an image of the website to give you an idea of what it looks like and to make it easier for me to explain. The white tabs are controlled by Ajax and all of them are loaded when the Orders/Subscriptions page is loaded.

All the rows in the table are clickable, and the blue cogwheel shows a dropdown when you hover over it. This dropdown contains several links that need the javascript/jquery code to not activate the row link instead. The problem is that when you switch tabs, the js code won't run unless you reload the page (the active tab stays when reloaded), but the users of the website shouldn't have to reload the page every time they switch between the tabs.

I have absolutely no idea why the .js file only works on the active tab. Everything is written in Wicket/Java using a lot of Ajax events for this page.

[image: website]

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    alert('Propagination Stopped');
});
```

**EDIT:**
Alright, so I now know it works if I add

```
location.reload();
```

when the tabs are clicked, but I kinda want to avoid this since that adds unnecessary loading time.

Comment: Is the DOM of each tab already loaded or it is only loaded when the user clicks it? The javascript events will only be bound to whatever tabs are currently loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Where are your `script` tags? What makes you expect the browser to decide to run them more than once? What does the code loading the tab content look like?

Comment: @Watercolours: The posted code doesn't help. What is `tabbedPanelAjax`? What is `orderResponsePanel`? What is `subscriptionsResponsePanel`? What markup do they define? What gets sent to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Since I use Ajax for the tabs I had to add 
`$(document).ajaxComplete(function { myFunction });`

and put the `onClick` in there. That way it would load properly every time I switched tabs.

The invisible tables in the inactive tabs had `display: none;` which mean when they are set to `display: visible;` it isn't part of the DOM. So the script won't run unless page is reloaded.

Don't like answering my own question, but felt like the info should be shared.

Thanks for the help anyways guys!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how your script elements are defined and added to the DOM, so it's hard to be specific.

Once a `script` element has been added to the DOM (directly, or via markup), it is run **once**. If you want any functions defined by that script to be run again, you have to run them. So in your tab-switching code, add code to call a function if you want it to be run for that tab.

You also haven't shown how you're loading the tab content, or whether the tab content defines `script` tags. It's best **not** to have the tab content contain any more script than necessary. Instead, have a main script file loaded with the page that defines the main functions, and then *at most* have a single `script` in the dynamically-loaded tab content that executes a single function call to that already-loaded code. If you're loading via jQuery's `load`, it'll call the scripts for you unless you use a fragment identifier with `load`. (If you use a fragment identifier with `load`, it disregards scripts in the content entirely.)

Comment: The script is added in the head of the page. You might be right when you say it's not loaded for the other tabs. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Watercolours: *"...it's not loaded for the other tabs."* The tabs in your page are not in separate JavaScript environments (barring some Wicket magic). If the code is loaded on the page, it's loaded on the *page*. Individual tabs don't come into it, the page is a single environment.

Comment: I know it's loaded for the whole page, and it is NOT a separate document. The JavaScript document controls a lot on the website, and EVERYTHING except this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you!
the html code example

```
<ul id="ajaxContainer">
    <li>the default content in your app</li>
</ul>
<nav id="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="/ajaxpath1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ajaxpath2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ajaxpath2">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="jquerypath/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="appjspath/app.js"></script>
```

Code in your app.js as bellow

```
$(function() {
    var $ajaxContainer = $('#ajaxContainer'),
        CLSA = "active",
        DOT = ".",
        $pagination = $('#pagination'),
        hasElMakeShow = function($el) {
            //just make elment show hide
            $el.show().siblings().hide();
        },
        appendNewEl = function($el) {
            //new data requested should be append to container element
            $ajaxContainer.append($el);
            hasElMakeShow($el);
        },
        initBindEl = function(){
            //init bind first active pagination el with its data elment
            var $li = $ajaxContainer.find('>li'),
                $active = $pagination.find(DOT + CLSA);
            $active.data('el', $li);
        },
        switchNavA = function($el) {
           //do some pagination switch active class work
           $el.addClass(CLSA).closest('li').siblings().removeClass(CLSA);
        };

    initBindEl();//first bind current pagination

    $pagination.delegate('>li a', 'click.page', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//prevent default jump
        var $me = $(this),
            isActive = $me.is(DOT + CLSA),
            $targetEl = $me.data('el');
        if(!isActive) {
            if($targetEl.length) {
                hasElMakeShow($targetEl);
            } else {
                var url = $me.attr('href');
                $.get(url, function(data){
                    var $respondEl = $(data);
                    $me.data('el', $respondEl);
                    appendNewEl($respondEl);
                    switchNavA($me);
                });
            }
        }

  });
});
```

Comment: Not what was looking for at all. Sorry, but thanks for trying! :)